# Linux — accessing content on mounted drive

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server

I have to make some files accessible from a shared network drive on a website.

I was able to successfully "mount" the drive in one of my folder in my linux (debian) machine. When I go to it, however, I can't go into the directories.

For example:

```
cd FOLDER_NAME
```

Gives me "Invalid Argument".

I can use my ftp client to navigate to the mounted directory, but when I try going to one of the directories inside, I get an error (badly formatted packet or protocol incompatibility). Error code: 5 (WinSCP).

I've never done this before, how would I access the contents?

Thanks!

Comment: More info please. What protocol do you use for mounting remote drive? How do you verify that it mounted successfully? Did you gave the mount point correct permissions prior to mounting?

Comment: Permission problem...

Comment: I used the following to mount:
mount -t cifs //1.1.1.1/path /var/www/tempdir -o user=sampleuser,password="samplepass"

Comment: would definitely be helpful to know if you had su access or not, however also just double check that you aren't having issues with typo's. I know in some cases I have files with quite a few "- _ . "s in them and linux is picky in the sense that it wants the exact name. if not typo could be permissions issue as the others have already stated

Comment: @Alex Do you mean permissions from within my linux machine or permissions on the shared network drive in windows?

Comment: also from what point of view are you trying to access those files? did you mount the files as SU and then create a sample user to try to access them as sample? If this is the case file permissions are more than likely the culprit. If it is indeed file permissions you may need to log back in as SU and change the permissions for the specified folder

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms I was logged in as root when used the mount command. The username and password are just my windows username / password. I can see the Folders just can't access them.

Comment: and from what medium are you trying to access them, winscp? One possible culprit could be to make sure that you have connected as "SFTP" through win scp settings. My manager had an issue with ftp vs sftp using filezilla once. Also if that still doesn't work what type of files are they? Did you mount from an iso? or something that can't necesarilly be "opened"? If all else fails the last thing I could reccomend is set max file permissions for test case to see if you can access the directory. chmod 777 "dir-name" then try to access

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms I'm trying to access through both SSH and WinScp. Can't get in with either.

Comment: Try to browse mounted share as root. Would it work?

Comment: @Alex Nope. I try "cd FolderName" and I get "cd: FolderName: Invalid Argument"

Comment: Looks like you mounted windows share that has paths from windows's shortcut. Try to share on windows some actual (non symlinked) directory and mount it in Linux and try again if you can browse it.

Comment: @Alex How would I be able to see if it's a non symlinked directory?

Comment: Make sure that windows share support CIFS (it outdated protocol that turned off on recent windows). you can turn it on from control panel->programs and features->turn windows features on/off. When you mounting windows share try also CIFS option `-o vers=1.0` then try `-o vers=2.0` or `-o vers=2.1`

Comment: @Alex I tried adding the vers=1.0 at the end and it just gave me usage instructions for the mount command. Full syntax I used was:
mount -t cifs //1.1.1.1/path /var/www/tempdir user=sampleuser,password="samplepass" -o vers=1.0

Comment: It should work, use `mount.cifs` insted on `mount`. Options I posted previously is in the official debian's manual: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cifs-utils/mount.cifs.8.en.html

Comment: @Alex I think I'm close. I used mount.cifs //1.1.1.1/dfs /var/www/newtemppdfs username=sampleuser,password="samplepass" -o vers=1.0

But then it asked me for the password for root@1.1.1.1

I'm not trying to log in with with root though, just sampleuser.